# Tkinter window is different when I run my program from terminal

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program with a GUI using Tkinter. I want to convert the script to an exe file, but when I do the window gets scaled way bigger so that some of the widgets are of screen compared to when I've run the program in Thonny. This also happens if I run the script from terminal. [Window when run from Thonny.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh1ap.png) [Window when run from exe file or terminal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRhYZ.png)